# What's a good way to create 1MB String?

Tags: java, string

I want to create 1MB String for benchmark,so I writed code as follow:

```
public final static long KB     = 1024;
public final static long MB     = 1024 * KB;
public static void main(String[] args){
    String text_1MB=createString(1*MB);
}
static String createString(long size){
    StringBuffer o=new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        o.append("f");
    }
    return o.toString();
}
```

I feel that this method `createString` is not good and stupid

Any idea to optimize the `createString` method?

Comment: Note that that string would be 2 MiB in size.

Comment: hi @Joey ,What's the meaning of "2 MiB in size"?

Comment: It's a string consisting of 1048576 character, each of which is a UTF-16 code unit. Therefore your string doesn't have 1 MiB but 2.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about:

```
char[] chars = new char[size];
// Optional step - unnecessary if you're happy with the array being full of \0
Arrays.fill(chars, 'f');
return new String(chars);
```

Comment: I think using Arrays class is clever since it calls a method only once while the Append method of another class has to be called many times.

Answer (score 10):

You can simply create a large character array.

```
char[] data = new char[1000000];
```

If you need to make a real `String` object, you can:

```
String str = new String(data);
```

Comment: The OP is already not using += in a loop - the code in the question uses StringBuffer.

Answer (score 4):

```
char[] s = new char[1024 * 1000];
String str = String.copyValueOf(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a character array and use `new String(char[])` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

How about using class StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer? StringBuilder should be faster since it is not synchronized unlike StringBuffer.

Perhaps you can increase performance by setting the compiler flags to increase the Heap memory and Virtual memory. It can not hurt certainly.

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder and set the capacity:

```
static String createString(long size){
    StringBuilder o=new StringBuilder(size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        o.append("f");
    }
    return o.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new String(ByteBuffer.allocate(1024).array());
```

Allocate a 1024 byte ByteBuffer, then construct new String out of its backing array.